# Does the limit of $ye^{-1/x}$ as $(x, y)\to (0, 2)$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)} ye^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$

Does this limit exist? Or does the limit not exist?

Comment: What happens when $x\to 0$?

Comment: Fix $y=2$ and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is what will happen to $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ when $x \rightarrow 0$, because there is no problem for $y$ if $y \rightarrow 2$.

Then, one important fact you need to know is that, if a limit exists, then the its left limit and right limit have to be euqal. But here, you see

$$x \rightarrow 0^+, \frac{-1}{x} \rightarrow -\infty$$

and

$$x \rightarrow 0^-, \frac{-1}{x} \rightarrow +\infty$$

And since

$$e^{-\infty} = 0 \neq +\infty = e^{+\infty}$$

we can conclude that the limit of $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ doesn't exist.